# Fragment Master-Details with saved State

Tags: android, fragment, resume, fragment-lifecycle

In an activity there is a fragment that contains a list of objects. This fragment should be replaced by another fragment that contains details of a list item. When the detail fragment is active and the back button is pressed then the listfragment should be resumed.

my code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            if (detailsFragment.isVisible())
            {
                goToListFragment();
            }
        }
    }

    public void goToListFragment() {
        String backStateName = listFragment.getClass().getName();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = fm.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

        if (!fragmentPopped){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, listFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commit();
        }


    }

    public void goToDetailsFragment(String foodAsJSON) {    
        String backStateName = detailsFragment.getClass().getName();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, detailsFragment)
                .addToBackStack(backStateName)
                .commit();
    }
```

what I observe:

```
listfragment: onPause() 
<back pressed in details view>
listfragment: oncreateView()
listfragment: onResume()
```

So, when the back button is pressed I would expect that only the **onResume** function is called. Actually that how its described in the fragment lifecycle. But as I have observed the **oncreateView()** is called too. That causes the fragment to reload completely and that's not the wanted behavior. So, how do I resume the master fragment properly?

Comment: What about using `add` instead of `replace`  while moving to details fragment ?

Comment: ah, that works kind of. but now my details fragment is not drawn properly.

Comment: great do you know the reason for why it worked ?? or should i post a answer explaining that ?

Comment: I edited my answer - It seems now my details view is not correctly drawn. I see some elements of my listfragments. It looks like draw() function or so is missing

Comment: It is because the listfragment is in the view we have just added the detail fragment over list fragment

Comment: Does your detail fragment have a transparent background ??